# How to create stacked bar grpah in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I want to create some stacked bar like at this [link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html)

This is my code:

```
data = [{'KW' : 1912927, 'ZOB': 873123},
      {'KW' : 1912927, 'ZOB': 873123}]
#stacked#
N=5
ZOB = df1['ZOB']
KW = df1['KW']
##location x and width##
ind= np.arange(N)
width = 0.35
#plot#
p1 = plt.bar(ind, ZOB, width)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, KW, width)

plt.ylabel('Wartość w zł')
plt.show()
```

But I get error shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.

Comment: `df.plot.bar(stacked=True)`

Comment: `df.plot.bar(stacked=True)` is the way to. But if you really want to follow the linked old example, you need to set `N=2` and also change the second bar plot to `plt.bar(ind, KW, width, bottom=ZOB)`.